# Why hydrogen peroxide sizzles in the bathroom sink?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Extremely short question. I pour a bit of hydrogen peroxide in my bathroom sink and it starts to sizzle, almost the same way it does on the open wound. Why? What elements in there it reacts with?

Comment: Decomposition of hydrogen peroxide is catalyzed by a great many compounds. It could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydrogen peroxide contains an peroxide linkage and it decompses rapidly to give oxygen.

But when substances like **detergent** come in its contact in a bathroom (as in the question) it not only  catalyses the reaction but if it was a foam making detergent it would make the decomposition process more evident and visible as oxygen bubble would produce effervescence in foam.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that even common bathroom soap stains will make the H2O2 make visible and audible reaction there?